# Blurry/wavy lines on HELP 2017 Nissan Rogue after installing aftermarket kenwood radio

Tags: nissan, audio, camera, rogue

I want to start by saying that i am not the most car savvy guy. This is why i’m here for help :)

I replaced my factory 2017 Nissan Rogue radio for a kenwood 6.2 inch aftermarket radio. This caused our reverse camera to need a 12v to 6v adapter since the radio sends a 12 volt signal instead of 6. The adapter should have remedied this issue, but the reverse cam is blurry and wavy and hard to see. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to make my camera clear? I’ll literally buy anything, i just don’t know what will help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the camera you are hooking to is the stock one which came with the Rogue?

Comment: What aspect of the installation leads you to expect 6v at the vehicle camera?

Comment: Yes it’s the stock camera. I was told by the installer that the radio sends a 12v signal, whereas the factory radio had only sent a 6v to activate the camera. The camera was not blurry with the factory radio and then became blurry/wavy after installing the aftermarket kenwood radio. Let me know it anymore information would be helpful :) i appreciate you responding!